# Home folder icons dont change

Tags: 12.10, icons

I just installed [my-humanity icon theme](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/use-ubuntu-1304-software-center.html) on my Ubuntu 12.10, but I have an issue:

I extracted the archive to `/usr/share/icons` or/and to `~/.icons` but when I applied the icon theme from the gnome tweak tool, the home folders icons don't update, but stay as Ubuntu mono dark default icons. Only the Launcher/tray icons change.

I attached screenshots in order for you to understand what my issue is:
My folder icons on home:

[image]

How they should be :

[image]

Any ideas on how can I fix it ?
Note : On nautilus as root (gksudo nautilus) they appear how they should be ... only they do not for the user!

Comment: Could it be that you started gnome-tweak-tool using `sudo`? because then you would have applied the changes only to the root account.

Comment: I think i found whats the problem but dont know how to fix it : In nautilus preferences i have changed the icon size to 66% from 100% and my-humanity theme has these icons only when icons are 100% . When i change icons size to 100% everything is ok !
Is there any solution to apply the icons when i decrease icon size to 66% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think i found whats the problem but dont know how to fix it : In nautilus preferences i have changed the icon size to 66% from 100% and my-humanity theme has these icons only when icons are 100% . When i change icons size to 100% everything is ok ! Is there any solution to apply the icons when i decrease icon size to 66% ?

The theme use different images for the 32, 24, 22, 16 pixels icons.

You can solve this copying the 48px icons in the 32, 24, 22 and 16 folders in the theme directory, this works fine for me.

Comment: I did that but the icons still being bigger ! Anyway i think i have to resize them manually :-)

Comment: I try it and the icons size change normally, are you sure that the icons are bigger?